# Swing MVC - refresh the content of JComboBox while already visible

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, uirefreshcontrol, comboboxmodel

I set the model of my combobox in my controller class

`cboCategory.setModel(new ModernDefaultComboBoxModel(model.getProductCategories()));`

`productCategories` is a `List` of `String`. `ModernDefaultComboBoxModel` is just model that extends `DefaultComboBoxModel`.

```
public class ModernDefaultComboBoxModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel{
    public ModernDefaultComboBoxModel(List<String> elements){
        super(elements.toArray());
    }
}
```

Now in my model, `productCategories` is populated from the DB, in a `SwingWorker`

```
SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        //query and resultset stuff
        while (rs.next()) {
            publish(rs.getString(1));
        }
        //cleanup stuff
    }
    @Override protected void process(List<String> chunks){
        List<String> oldCategories = new ArrayList<String>(productCategories);
        for(String cat : chunks){
            productCategories.add(cat);
        }
        fireModelPropertyChange(PRODUCT_CATEGORIES, oldCategories, productCategories);
    }
    @Override
    protected void done(){
        //some stuff
    }
};
worker.execute();
```

You see every `publish`, it fires a property change event to its listener (`fireModelPropertyChange` is just a wrapper for `firePropertyChange`).

Now in my model listener,

```
@Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        String propName = evt.getPropertyName();

        //some branching for the other models

        else if(ProductModel.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES.equals(propName)){
            List<String> newVal = (List<String>)evt.getNewValue();

            //notify the model of the combobox that the data is changed, so refresh urself
        }

        //some stuff
    }
```

I'm stuck in the part where my `ModelListener` needs to notify the combobox in the view that data in its model are changed. I have the same situation with `JTable` but with `JTable` I can just call `fireTableRowsInserted` of from its model which is implemented from `AbstractTableModel`.

Actually, in the `AbstractListModel` there is a method `fireContentsChanged` but unlike in the `JTable`, this method is protected so I can't access it.

I know I can just create an instance of `ModernDefaultComboBoxModel` then call the `setModel` method of the combobox  to refresh the combobox, but I'm just wondering if there is a "cleaner" way as clean as that of `JTable`

Comment: never-ever change the underlying data-structure of a model under its feet (and _never_ call any of its fireXX methods form outside code, that's the inherent responsibility of the model itself) - instead, use model api to add new items

Comment: Ah ok. So is the case also the same for JTable? No right because we can't add data to JTable (like the `addItem` of JComboBox)

Comment: @kleopatra is correct; it looks like you are planning to register your `ModernDefaultComboBoxModel` as listener to your application's data model and update the combo box model correctly; the combo view will follow.

Comment: Do you mean I don't need to do this? Then instead just call the combobox's `addItem` in my application model's listener to add the processed data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JComboBox` implements `ListDataListener` in order to listen to its own `ComboBoxModel`. Any change to your `DefaultComboBoxModel` should invoke the relevant `fireXxxx()` method in `AbstractListModel`, and the `JComboBox` should see the change. Just update the combo's model in `process()`.

Addendum: Here's a minimal example that updates the model. Set a breakpoint on `model.addElement()`, debug,  click on <kbd>Add</kbd>, and step into the method to see the call to `fireIntervalAdded()`, which subsequently updates the view.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("ComboWorkerTest");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
final JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox(new Integer[]{value});
f.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) jcb.getModel();
        model.addElement(++value);
    }
}));
f.add(jcb);
f.pack();
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: But my model has no access to the view there for I can't do `combobox.getModel`. It can only update the data of my combobox's model. So how can I do this?

Comment: You can pass a reference to the combo's model into your worker, or your worker can fire a `PropertyChangeEvent` to which your `ModernDefaultComboBoxModel` listens.

Comment: Ah ok so I can also register `ModernDefaultComboBoxModel` as a listener to my main model. Thank u.